# Высота блока в зависимости от содержимого с float: left

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! 
Суть проблемы: есть большой блок, который должен автоматически увеличиваться в зависимости от кол-ва маленьких блоков внутри него. У маленьких блоков есть правило float: left.

Нужно чтобы блок **.container** увеличивался в длину, в зависимости от того, сколько там **.block**, сколько всего их будет неизвестно (не меньше одного).

Заранее **большое спасибо**!

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="block"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   width: 800px;
   height: auto;
}

.content {
   width: 600px;
   height: auto;
   min-height: 500px;
   float: left;
}

.sidebar {
   width: 200px;
   height: 350px;
   float: right;
}

.block {
   width: 600px;
   height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: у тебя же ширина ему прописана. он не будет растягиваться с шириной

Comment: Надо чтобы растягивался в длину, а не ширину. Ширина статична.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow: hidden ему